# Node app.js use function how its recommended

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im having node app which using express i've server.js app.js etc

I need to use as middelware the following code

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

app.use(upload.single('file'));

app.use('/', rot, function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

But before the var `upload = multer...` I want to run the following 
code

```
var mkdirSync = function (path) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(path);
    } catch(e) {
        if ( e.code != 'EEXIST' ) throw e;
    }
}


mkdirSync( 'uploads/');
```

**How should I do it nicely?** add the code of mkdir before the upload multer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another middleware for this purpose, since `app.use` accepts multiple middleware functions.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    fs.mkdir(path, function(e){
        if(!!e && e.code !== 'EEXIST'){
            next(e);
            return;
        }
        next();
    });
}, upload.single('file'));
```

The above code should work. When you pass an error into the `next` middleware, express will know to skip all the following middleware functions and go straight to the error handler.

EDIT: I would recommend using the non-sync version of mkdir, and avoiding the `try/catch` block altogether.

EDIT 2: Maybe I am mistaken, and all you are looking to do is make sure the `storage` directory exists? If this is the case then simply doing the following will work:

```
mkdirSync(storage);

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

app.use(upload.single('file'));

app.use('/', rot, function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks I try it but it doesnt work I need that the upload will be done after the mkdir and when I change the order I got error...

Comment: What is the `<path>` that you want to create? The above code will definitely make sure mkdir is called before upload, that is the way express middleware works!

Comment: Ok, can you please explain why you suggest to use the async version?

Comment: The async version will prevent your code from blocking other operations. If you get 2 simultaneous requests, and you are running some sync code, you will only be able to handle 1 request while the sync code is running.

Comment: are you sure I can pass the storage here mkdirSync(storage); ? this give an error..

Comment: Ok I chage it to your first suggestion and it works 1+ currently two questions 1. can I write it in other file and call it on the app.js nicley ? 2. how can I write this code diffrent       if(!!e && e.code !== 'EEXIST'){
            next(e);
            return;
        }

Comment: You can put it in another file and just call it from app.js. As for the error code check, what are you looking for in terms of writing it differently?

Answer (score -1):

Its better to do like this.

//dir.js

```
exports.makeDir = function(path) {

    console.log(path);
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(path);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.code != 'EEXIST') throw e;
    }
}
```

And in your app.js

```
var varMkDir = require('./dir');


app.use(varMkDir.makeDir('uploads/'));
```

EDIT :

```
app.use(function(){

    varMkDir.makeDir('uploads/');
})
```

Comment: when I try it I got error app.use() requires middleware functions